# Build with libpqxx in C++11 on Kdevelop

Tags: c++11, libpqxx

I'm trying to build a C++ program, that needs lipqxx functionalities. I'm on Ubuntu and I'm trying to use Kdevelop.

I did it successfully with Code::Blocks, but I'm trying to find a better IDE.

Now, what I've done with Kdevelop. 
I created a simple example:

```
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pqxx::connection c("dbname=xx host=localhost user=xx password=xx");
    return 0;
}
```

I modified the CmakeList.txt to include the pqxx directory and to link with libpqxx.so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(testkdev)

include_directories ("/usr/include/pqxx")

LINK_DIRECTORIES("/usr/lib")

add_executable(testkdev main.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testkdev libpqxx.so)

install(TARGETS testkdev RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

At this point, the build process **works**.

But I need to do something else, I want to work in C++11.
So I add a -std=c++11 option, right clicking on my project, Open Configuration > Cmake > Advanced Values > CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.

And I get the following errors:

```
/home/francis/projects/testKDEV/build> make -j2
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/testkdev.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:79:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/tr1/memory:39,
                 from /usr/include/pqxx/util.hxx:31,
                 from /usr/include/pqxx/util:18,
                 from /usr/include/pqxx/except.hxx:27,
                 from /usr/include/pqxx/except:19,
                 from /usr/include/pqxx/result.hxx:33,
                 from /usr/include/pqxx/result:19,
                 from /usr/include/pqxx/binarystring.hxx:26,
                 from /usr/include/pqxx/binarystring:18,
                 from /usr/include/pqxx/pqxx:17,
                 from /home/francis/projects/testKDEV/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1034:20: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
     : tuple_element<__i, _Tuple> { };
                    ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1034:20: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1034:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1054:17: error: ‘tuple_size’ was not declared in this scope
          (__i < tuple_size<_Tuple>::value)>
                 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1054:35: error: ‘::value’ has not been declared
          (__i < tuple_size<_Tuple>::value)>
```

and it goes on and on with errors...
Could anybody please help me understanding what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Kdevelop but I had similar problem. I use Eclipse. There is my question and answer. That is in Polish, so find someone, who can translate that. My English isn't too good but I'm going to transtalte as well as I can.

[My question (forum.dobreprogramy.pl)](http://forum.dobreprogramy.pl/postgresql-i-c11-jaka-biblioteka-517085t.html)

You need libpqxx-4.0.1. Download these packages:

- [md5sum](http://pqxx.org/download/software/libpqxx/libpqxx-4.0.1.tar.gz.md5sum)
- [libpqxx-4.0.1](http://pqxx.org/download/software/libpqxx/libpqxx-4.0.1.tar.gz)

Next:

1. check package: md5sum -c libpqxx-4.0.1.tar.gz.md5sum
2. If it's ok: tar -xzvf libpqxx-4.0.1.tar.gz
3. cd libpqxx-4.0.1
4. ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared

You can choose path other than "/usr/local". There will be installed libpqxx.

5. make clean
6. make
7. make install

Now you should have header files in /usr/local/include and libpqxx.a, libpqxx.so in /usr/local/lib. If everything is ok, link libraries in IDE. I don't know, how to do this in your IDE but this is generally the same but properties are in different places. For example in Eclipse CDT:

1. In Project/properties/C\C++ Buid/Settings/GCC C++ Compiler/Includes/include paths type: /usr/local/include
2. In GCC C++ Linker/Libraries/Library search path type: /usr/local/lib
3. In GCC C++ Linker/Libraries/Libraries type: pqxx
4. In project: #include

Now try to compile. If it's ok, try to run program. If you have problem like in post #15

```
error while loading shared libraries: libpqxx-4.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

1. Go to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ and make there new file named libpqxx-4.0.1.conf next open the file nad type there /usr/local/lib
2. After that issue the command ldconfig

In my case it was everything to connect with PostgreSQL using libpqxx and C++11. Good luck.